# WebDAV doesn't include BCC headers when retrieving mail

Tags: exchange-server, webdav

This seems to be intended behaviour as stated [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/webdav_101/archive/2008/04/24/why-can-t-webdav-read-bcc.aspx), but I can't believe the only method of getting the BCCs is to parse Outlook Web Access' HTML code.

Has anybody encountered the same limitation and found a workaround? I'd also be fine with getting the BCCs from somewhere via WebDAV and adding the header fields myself.

Answer (score 1):

BCC, by definition, doesn't create nor use any of the headers in an e-mail message.  It wouldn't be "blind" otherwise, no?

Comment: The corresponding MAPI property is there. The BCC info is stripped by Exchange when retrieving the email.